# Achieving stable 60fps with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, game-development, sdl-2

I was struggling to find information on what is the industry standard on how to achieve stable 60 fps in a game that uses SDL2 and after reading a bunch of articles, I iterated through different ideas until I was able to measure 60 (+- 0.1) fps in my game.

Below is my current approach and I am looking for validation that it is not completely wrong / correction about how actual games (2D) do it.

```
const float TARGET_FPS = 60.04f;
const float SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME = 1000.0f / static_cast<float>(TARGET_FPS);
...
class Timer{
public:
    Uint64 started_ticks = 0;

    Timer()
            :started_ticks{SDL_GetPerformanceCounter()}
    {}

    void restart() {
        started_ticks = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    }

    float get_time() {
        return (static_cast<float>(SDL_GetPerformanceCounter() - started_ticks) / static_cast<float>(SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency()) * 1000.0f);
    }
};

...

float extra_time{0};
Timer fps_cap_timer{};

while(game_loop_condition){
    fps_cap_timer.restart();
    ...
    render();
    while((fps_cap_timer.get_time() + extra_time) < SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME) {
            SDL_Delay(1); // I am aware of the issues with delay on different platforms / OS scheduling
        }
    if (fps_cap_timer.get_time() < (SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME)) {
            extra_time -= SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME - fps_cap_timer.get_time();
        }
        else {
            extra_time += fps_cap_timer.get_time() - SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME;
        }
}
```

With this approach, there is always a little extra time that fluctuates between 0 - 1ms, which leads to FPS slightly <60, therefore I adjusted the target FPS to 60.04 and I am getting 60±0.1 FPS.

So.. is this actually viable or did I screw something up and should do more reading on the topic?

Comment: I'd just enable VSync and accept whatever FPS it gives you. Then you don't really need `SDL_Delay()` (except that for me the automatic delay that VSync added was consuming 100% of one core, so I added a shorter `SDL_Delay` before that to reduce the load a bit, and then let VSync do the precise final wait).

Comment: I don’t want to rely purely on VSync since it can be disabled in drivers (and other reasons), at least I want to have a solid backup system.

Comment: If the user went out of their way to disable vsync, I'd just give them unlocked FPS, or *approximately* their refresh rate (approximated with `SDL_Delay()`) (should probably aim towards the screen refresh rate, not 60). Your game logic should be [decoupled from the FPS anyway](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), so if the FPS is off on some weird configurations, it won't really affect anything.

Comment: [Gaffer On Games](https://gafferongames.com/) (articles are in reverse chronological order), start bottom left with [Integration Basics](https://gafferongames.com/post/integration_basics/) then [Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), etc... Great discussion of game loops, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Relying on FPS is not usually how it's done. Instead, measure the time since the last frame and use that as a multiplier for how far your game objects have moved.

Having a rather precise FPS may be wanted in some situations though, but since you restart the timer in every iteration of the loop, it's going to drift. I suggest just adding a fixed duration to the timer and wait until that point in time occurs. Using only standard library classes and functions, it could look like this:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::intmax_t FPS>
class Timer {
public:
    // initialize Timer with the current time point:
    Timer() : tp{std::chrono::steady_clock::now()} {}

    // a fixed duration with a length of 1/FPS seconds
    static constexpr std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, FPS>>
        time_between_frames{1};

    void sleep() {
        // add to the stored time point
        tp += time_between_frames;

        // and sleep almost until the new time point
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp - std::chrono::microseconds(100));

        // less than 100 microseconds busy wait
        while(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() < tp) {}
    }

private:
    // the time point we'll add to in every loop
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,
                            std::remove_const_t<decltype(time_between_frames)>> tp;
};
```

The busy waiting is there to make the FPS as accurate as possible, but it eats CPU so you want to keep it as short as possible. 100µs may be too much so you can make it shorter or even remove it if you find the accuracy good enough without it.

Then your game loop would be:

```
int main() {
    // setup ...

    Timer<60> fps_cap_timer; // 60 FPS
    while(game_loop_condition) {
        render();
        fps_cap_timer.sleep(); // let it sleep any time remaining
    }
}
```

Comment: UV because usage of `fps_cap_timer.sleep()`. It not only sleeps the time remaining but also keeps the CPU usage low.

Comment: @knoxgon Thanks! Removing the busy waiting part will make it consume even less CPU but I put it there just to get it as close to the target as I could. :)

Comment: I am aware that game logic shouldn't be related to FPS, I simply wish to render the game at steady 60 FPS, is that unreasonable? My understanding is that nearly every game does it.

It looks like I can achieve better precision with `sleep_until` instead of `SDL_Delay`, is that the reason to use it?

Comment: @m4dolaf _"is that unreasonable"_ - You decide what you want. It may not be _necessary_ to do it though. `sleep_until` isn't inherently more accurate than `SDL_Delay` but sleeping until a precalculated time point and not resetting the timer in every iteration of the loop will be more accurate than your current approach. I see that `SDL_Delay(1)` means sleeping a whole millisecond and then you reset the timer. Drifting will occur.

Comment: Hm, my rationale was that since the best resolution I can get is 1 millisecond, any kind of sleep will inherently lead to an imprecise outcome, therefore I am then storing the imprecision in `extra_time` and correcting for it in the next frames to balance it out and achieve correct FPS on average. I don't understand why resetting the timer is an issue, since all the information that is transferred between frames is in the `extra_time`.

Comment: @m4dolaf I'm unsure about if your `extra_time` solves that issue. You call `get_time` 3 times and get different values each time. It's hard to see how that can add up to eaven it out at 60 FPS - and since you asked the question, it does not work. Did you try my replacement? If that doesn't get you very very close to 60 FPS on average (with some +- for individual frames) I'd be surprised.

Comment: Also, could you clarify why aiming for a steady 60 FPS might be unnecessary? I don't really understand it. Is it because of VSync?

Comment: @m4dolaf It's not necessary of you instead use the delta time as suggested.

Comment: But delta time is a matter of updating the game state based on real-time instead of framerate, right? If my code outputed at 57 FPS, the game wouldn't look very good even though the game state would be correct.

I haven't tried your replacement yet, but my code gets me very close to 60 FPS on average too (+- 0.05-0.1), but I am of course interested in the flaws that you see in it. I don't see what is wrong with `get_time` returning different value each time, that is actually what it should do since it measures how long constructing the frame took (and that is always different).

Comment: @m4dolaf Using the delta time instead of relying on a fixed FPS will usually look better. Why wouldn't it look good at 57 FPS or 120 FPS? What I mean with `get_time` being called multiple times is that you call it multiple times _after_ the `render()`  step + delay loop. `if (fps_cap_timer.get_time() < (SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME))` - If that condition is `true` it, it may no longer be `true` when you then do `extra_time -= SCREEN_TICKS_PER_FRAME - fps_cap_timer.get_time();` etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, rendering at 57 FPS (or lower number) == less frequent updates with larger changes on the scene, which is not desirable.

I see your point about `get_time` now, thanks.

Comment: @m4dolaf You're welcome! Sure, there's a limit at which point it starts looking "laggy" but above that, the _actual_ FPS shouldn't matter that much. It'll be interesting to hear what FPS you get with my suggestion once you try it out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have tested your method and indeed I am able to achieve `59.9998` average FPS, which is awesome, thanks a lot. I am wondering about the `SDL_Delay` vs. `sleep_until` precision. My understanding is that `SDL_Delay` has a precision of 1 millisecond while std::chrono has a platform-specific precision in nanoseconds (I've found about 40 nanoseconds for OSX which I currently use) and both have the same chance of issues due to OS scheduler. And that is why your implementation achieves such precise FPS. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo And strangely with your implementation I am suddenly experiencing a lot of screen tearing, which I never experienced with other implementations. Weird.

Comment: @m4dolaf I _think_ the `SDL_Delay` you have could be removed to improve accuracy in your original solution. It then becomes a busy wait loop just like the one I have in the `Timer::sleep()` function (after `sleep_until`). It will eat a lot of CPU though since you don't have a pre-sleep like the `sleep_until` I have. Screen tearing sounds bad :) I've never had that. Perhaps you should unaccept the answer, at least for now, to see if someone else comes in with a better solution?

Comment: The precision of `SDL_Delay` is probably similar to what `chrono::sleep_for` would give. It's `sleep_until` with calculated time points that makes it accurate. `sleep_until(T0 + std::chrono::duration<double>(frame_number / FPS))` if that makes sense.

Comment: @m4dolaf Could the tearing be because of the actual FPS now being close to a multiple of the Vsync somehow? I can't quite figure out if `SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC` should be used when creating the renderer or not in this case.

Comment: To be honest I didn't find a good resource on how to properly render without VSync and have no tearing. If I enable `SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC`, its perfectly smooth without any tearing. Any tips?

Comment: @m4dolaf I'm guessing here but I'm thinking that you should use that option when manually fixating the FPS. Do you get tearing if you use 63 FPS too?